# Why Do Dogs Hide Food?

Tags: dogs, diet

so,my 16 year old sister has a dog...A Black Peach Brown Pomeranian. So my dad would give her a sausage link, then she runs off hiding it under my sisters bed.
Then after a while she takes it outside with her then leaving it out there,leaving it through the day. Until the point it's rock hard,i don't really know whats going on.